# Application crashes when using SQLiteHelper and Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Application uses a database that is stored in assets.
Works perfectly on android 2.2
I added some Google map code so I changed from android 2.2 to GoogleAPIs 2.2 trough 
project->properties->android->Project Build Target

Now application crashes after starting activity that contains MySQLiteHelper pointer with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.etf.db/com.etf.db.TabContainer}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.etf.db/com.etf.db.QueryTab}: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: stations: , while compiling: (some query)
```

When remove all MySQLiteHelper pointers there are no RuntimeExceptions.

Comment: your database have `stations` table?

Comment: how is your database stored in assets?

Comment: I created myDatabase.db a placed it into assets folder.

`private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
   InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
   String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
   myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int length;
   while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
   }
   myOutput.flush();
   myOutput.close();
   myInput.close();
}`

When creating database I call copyDataBase()

Answer (score 0):

The below line in the exception output states that There is **no `stations` table exist actually.**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: stations: , while compiling: (some query)
```

Comment: Yes, but that table exists in myDatabase.db
That exception is thrown only on Google APIs 2.2 not on Android 2.2 for the same code.